# numpy difference between fft and rfft

Tags: numpy, fft

I'm trying to understand the difference between numpy `fft` and `rfft`. I've read the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft2.html#numpy.fft.rfft2), and it only says `rfft` is meant for real inputs.

I've tested their performance on a large real array and found out `rfft` is faster than `fft` by about a third. My question is: why is `rfft` fast? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously there will be a potential difference in performance between a general purpose routine which needs to be able to handle real and complex inputs, and one which is optimized only for real valued input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RFFT has half the degrees of freedom on the input, and half the number of complex outputs, compared to an FFT.  Thus the FFT computation tree can be pruned to remove those adds and multiplies not needed for the non-existent inputs and/or those unnecessary since there are a lesser number of independant output values that need to be computed.

This is because an FFT of a strictly real input (e.g. all the input value imaginary components zero) produces a complex conjugate mirrored result, where each half can be trivially derived from the other half.